# Iterate over certain vector which is part of a cell

Tags: matlab

I have a number of cells `A{1} ... A{n}`. Each cell contains a vector `a` hence `A{1}.a ... A{n}.a`. Now, is there an easy way (i.e. one line) to access an element from `a` i.e. `g = A{:}.a(2)` from all the cells? `g` is now a vector which contains the second element of `a` from all `A`-cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `cellfun`:

```
cellfun(@(x) x.a(2), A)
```

Comment: +1 nice simple answer, making use of a function that I hadn't ever used before! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: My pleasure.  Both `cellfun` and `arrayfun` are really great weapons to know.  Then there's `bsxfun`, but I've never really understood it.

Comment: I just discovered `bsxfun` ... oh the power! I haven't used `arrayfun` though... I'll have to read up on it.